# Двумерные массивы c# как в php

Tags: php, c#

Конструкция в php:

```
$array = Array(0 => Array("lol", "vol", "mol"), 1 => Array("pupa", "lupa"));
```

Как это реализовать в c# ?

Comment: Я бы не рекомендовал тупо переносить из PHP в c# подобную логику. Вам ООП в c# зачем дано, чтобы им не пользоваться?

Comment: Это именно та неделя в году, когда все пхпэшники обращаются в шарпистов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам очень хочется, то на C# это будет выглядеть так:

```
string[][] array = new string[2][];
array[0] = new string[3] { "lol", "vol", "mol" };
array[1] = new string[2] { "pupa", "lupa" };
```

Или вот более компактный эквивалент:

```
var array = new[] { new[] { "lol", "vol", "mol" }, new[] { "pupa", "lupa" } };
```

Однако, я вангую, что это не совсем то (или совсем не то), что нужно для решения вашей задачи. Массивы в C# представляют собой совершенно иную сущность нежели в php. И часто, в этих языках одна и та же задача решается по-разному. Поэтому, вряд ли у вас получится вот так с наскоку, не вникая в C#, перевести решение с php.